# All accordion open and close once at a time when opening/closing ONE

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use angular bootstrap ui 0.14.3.

When I click any of that dynamic generated accordions then ALL of them open/close. There is something wrong here.

I just want that only the one I click open/close.

I already have set close-others="true" but thats not working...

What do I wrong?

**Html**:

```
 <uib-accordion close-others="true">
            <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen" ng-repeat="t in tests">
                <uib-accordion-heading>
                    {{t.schoolclassCode}}

                    <span style="background:orange;">{{t.type}}</span>
                    <span style="background:green;">{{t.number}}</span>
                    <span style="background:aliceblue;">{{t.date}}</span>
                    <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.isFirstOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.isFirstOpen}"></i>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
                My dynamic content
            </uib-accordion-group>
        </uib-accordion>
```

**Controller**:

```
  function TestsController($scope, tests) {

        $scope.tests = tests;

        $scope.oneAtATime = true;


        $scope.status = {
            isFirstOpen: true,
            isFirstDisabled: false
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of your `is-open="status.isFirstOpen"` which is the same variable in all your `uib-accordion-group`. When you open or close one of your accordion, others are watching the same variable and will do the same. You have to use an array in order to define an unique variable for each of your accordion-group. I made you an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjLw2FcZQh4gQREpgoiz?p=preview).

```
<uib-accordion close-others="false">
<uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups track by $index" is-open="accordionArray[$index]">
  <uib-accordion-heading>
    {{group.title}}
    <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="accordionArray[$index] ? 'glyphicon-chevron-down':'glyphicon-chevron-right'"></i>
  </uib-accordion-heading>
  {{group.content}}
</uib-accordion-group>
```

and this in the controller `$scope.accordionArray = []`

Comment: It is in the scope, you can find it in the js file in the example [http://plnkr.co/edit/QjLw2FcZQh4gQREpgoiz?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjLw2FcZQh4gQREpgoiz?p=preview)